# Search bar for selected location and destination for google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-search

I have a autocomplete fragment for my search bar, what I want is for the user to choose if they want to use their current location or they will manually choose a starting location then the destination.

I have no idea what it is called or where I can find documentation for that kind of search bar. I would greatly appreciate any comments or suggestions!

Comment: Hello there! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what you have tried so far so that we can go from there or so that the community could help you better.